# choosing some (or none) elements of the array and adding them to get the expected sum

Tags: python

I have a simple problem if done manually,but I want to do this dynamically.

Consider a static array A = [3 2 0 7 -1]

Expected_sum S = 8

So from above array I can **manually** choose elements 2,7,-1 to get Sum = 2 + 7 + (-1) = 8

```
static code :

a = [3,2,0,7,-1]
exp_sum = 8

# manually choosing elements to get exp_sum
req_sum = exp_sum[1] + exp_sum[3] + exp_sum[4]   
if exp_sum == req_sum:
    print "Yes"
else:
    print "No"
```

Can somebody please explain me how can I do this dynamically if I get any size of array from user and also expected_sum from user.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should use [`Dynamic programming`](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/) for this purpose.

Comment: It's the famous `Subset Sum Problem` which can be solved using `Dynamic Programming`. You might find this useful: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/

Comment: @aradhak Thanks for the link, I will try to solve this using python

Comment: It seems that you're doing a lot of stuff lately that could benefit from Dynamic programming techniques. :) FWIW, I get 134 solutions for [your ANDing problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40818457/4014959). I found them by expressing the problem as an [Exact Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) problem, which I solved using Knuth's [Algorithm X](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~aassaf9/python/algorithm_x.html).